# Add additional data in tooltip of Highcharts with dynamic x-axis category

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want all months in a category like this:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
},
```

But here

xAxis: {
        categories: ['0', "1", "2", "3", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    },

However, as `may` and `jun` appears the tooltip shows `undefined`. I want to show data in tooltip like this `jan => A, feb => B, mar => C ... Dec => L`

http://jsfiddle.net/vuodamxk/1/

Can someone help me??

Comment: Eh, could you clarify your issue? Also, where is the php part?

Comment: in categories + series.data + Group data is comming from database via php..

Comment: no, this is example when i use 0,1,2,3 data becomes accurate A,B,C,D
but if i use jan,feb, mar it become undefined

i want jan,feb,march instead of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6...

Comment: Epodax can you help me where i m doing mistake.. or any one else help me????

Comment: nope, I don't know how it works, I'm a php guy and this isn't a php issue as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with getting your `GROUP` param:

```
GROUP = series.options.GROUP[point.x];
```

`point.x` is category name, so it returns accordingly `0`, `1` ... `May` ..

As you can see, there is no `index = May` in your `GROUP` array. Instead use `point.point.x` to get **index** of the category, not the category **name**. Like this:

```
GROUP = series.options.GROUP[point.point.x];
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vuodamxk/3/